# count total number of children and the total number of objects and split into different array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Here I am calculating total length of the array using reduce array method.

I want to split the array into two arrays if the length exceed 30 so the new array will have total is as shown in the snippet 53 here so : two new  [array1]  = length will be 30 + [array2]  = length will be 23

Any suggestions would be great :

```js
let array = [
    {
        "account": "0",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [
            {
                "account": "A",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "account": "1",
        "total": 3,
        "children": [
            {
                "account": "A",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "B",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "C",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "account": "2",
        "total": 3,
        "children": [
            {
                "account": "A",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "B",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "C",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "account": "3",
        "total": 12,
        "children": [
            {
                "account": "A",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "B",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "C",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "D",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "E",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "F",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            }, {
                "account": "G",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            }, {
                "account": "H",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            }, {
                "account": "I",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "J",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "K",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "L",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        "account": "4",
        "total": 16,
        "children": [
            {
                "account": "A",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "B",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "C",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "D",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "E",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "F",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            }, {
                "account": "G",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            }, {
                "account": "H",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            }, {
                "account": "I",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "J",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "K",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "L",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "M",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "N",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "0",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "P",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        "account": "5",
        "total": 12,
        "children": [
            {
                "account": "A",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "B",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "C",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "D",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "E",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "F",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            }, {
                "account": "G",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            }, {
                "account": "H",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            }, {
                "account": "I",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "J",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "K",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "L",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
        ],
    },
]

const lengthOfChildren = array.reduce( (acc, val) => acc + val.children.length, 0);

console.log(lengthOfChildren)

const lengthOfArrayObjects = Object.keys(array).length;

console.log(lengthOfArrayObjects)

const totalLength = lengthOfChildren + lengthOfArrayObjects;

console.log(totalLength)
```

Comment: Did the answer work out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each object has a `children` property, one option could be to recursively loop the children of each object, aggregating the objects without the children property in a multidimensional array.

If the array has 30 items, add a new array to the resulting array.

To not return an empty array, you can remove those at the end using array filter.

For example

```
const splitChildrenToArrays = (source, result, limit) => {
    const innerLoop = (source, result) => {
        source.forEach(item => {
            const {children, ...currObj} = item;
            result[0].push(currObj);
            if (result[0].length === limit) {
                result.unshift([]);
            }
            innerLoop(item.children, result);
        });
        return result;
    }
    return innerLoop(source, result).filter(i => i.length > 0);
}

const result = splitChildrenToArrays(array, [[]], 30);
```

```js
let array = [{
    "account": "0",
    "total": 1,
    "children": [{
      "account": "A",
      "total": 1,
      "children": [],
    }],
  },
  {
    "account": "1",
    "total": 3,
    "children": [{
        "account": "A",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "B",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "C",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "account": "2",
    "total": 3,
    "children": [{
        "account": "A",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "B",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "C",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "account": "3",
    "total": 12,
    "children": [{
        "account": "A",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "B",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "C",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "D",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "E",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "F",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      }, {
        "account": "G",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      }, {
        "account": "H",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      }, {
        "account": "I",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "J",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "K",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "L",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    "account": "4",
    "total": 16,
    "children": [{
        "account": "A",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "B",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "C",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "D",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "E",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "F",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      }, {
        "account": "G",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      }, {
        "account": "H",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      }, {
        "account": "I",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "J",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "K",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "L",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "M",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "N",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "0",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "P",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    "account": "5",
    "total": 12,
    "children": [{
        "account": "A",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "B",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "C",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "D",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "E",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "F",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      }, {
        "account": "G",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      }, {
        "account": "H",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      }, {
        "account": "I",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "J",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "K",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
      {
        "account": "L",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [],
      },
    ],
  },
]

const splitChildrenToArrays = (source, result, limit) => {
  const innerLoop = (source, result) => {
    source.forEach(item => {
      const {
        children,
        ...currObj
      } = item;
      result[0].push(currObj);
      if (result[0].length === limit) {
        result.unshift([]);
      }
      innerLoop(item.children, result);
    });
    return result;
  }
  return innerLoop(source, result).filter(i => i.length > 0);
}

console.log(splitChildrenToArrays(array, [
  []
], 30));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote a flatten function here : which takes all the clildren and bring the nested level data in a single level:

```js
let arrayofData = [
    {
        "account": "0",
        "total": 1,
        "children": [
            {
                "account": "A",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "account": "1",
        "total": 3,
        "children": [
            {
                "account": "A",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "B",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "C",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "account": "2",
        "total": 3,
        "children": [
            {
                "account": "A",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "B",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "C",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "account": "3",
        "total": 12,
        "children": [
            {
                "account": "A",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "B",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "C",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "D",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "E",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "F",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            }, {
                "account": "G",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            }, {
                "account": "H",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            }, {
                "account": "I",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "J",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "K",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "L",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        "account": "4",
        "total": 16,
        "children": [
            {
                "account": "A",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "B",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "C",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "D",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "E",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "F",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            }, {
                "account": "G",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            }, {
                "account": "H",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            }, {
                "account": "I",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "J",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "K",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "L",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "M",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "N",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "0",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "P",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        "account": "5",
        "total": 12,
        "children": [
            {
                "account": "A",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "B",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "C",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "D",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "E",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "F",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            }, {
                "account": "G",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            }, {
                "account": "H",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            }, {
                "account": "I",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "J",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "K",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
            {
                "account": "L",
                "total": 1,
                "children": [],
            },
        ],
    },]
    
 const flatten = (into, node) => {
  if (node == null) return into;
  if (Array.isArray(node)) return node.reduce(flatten, into);
  into.push(node);
  return flatten(into, node.children);
};
  //count per page
  let detailsPageLimit = 30;
  let detailsOut = flatten([], [arrayofData]);
  let numberOfDivisonDetails = Math.ceil(detailsOut.length / detailsPageLimit);

  let divisionsDetails = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfDivisonDetails; i++) {
    if (detailsOut.length > detailsPageLimit) {
      divisionsDetails.push(detailsOut.splice(0, detailsPageLimit));
    } else {
      divisionsDetails.push(detailsOut.splice(0, detailsOut.length));
    }
  }

console.log(divisionsDetails)
```